# Dual system-win 7-Ubuntu-Locatioin is not available

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, windows-8

I have a PC on which i install a dual system (win7 and Ubuntu 12.04).

Yesterday i used ubuntu and my external disk to copy some files from the disk. All files copied are from win7 system.

Then today on another PC(win8), when i try to open the dictionary on the external disk which contain all those files. I cant get access to the dictionary any more. The error read is :"Location is not available.....", Does any1 knows how to solve this?

Comment: The file was not copied properly.

Comment: There was an issue with the copying process.

Comment: You need to start over

Comment: I think i have not made any mistake during the copying process. Files are a little big, it took me some time to copy them. And by the way, i have also copied some files from the ubuntu system. Those files are all OK, i can open them

Comment: What file system did you use to format the external?

Comment: the external is formated in windows system, it is ntfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you copied soft links for the files. Can you share the properties of the file that you are trying to open in windows system?

Comment: I think i have not copied the soft links coz i did it the same way when trying to copy files in ubuntu system, and it took long time to copy them.

Comment: plz share the properties of the directory. one reason may be that your windows system is infected.

Comment: It seems a little wired that i can open all those files in another Linux system(fedora 22), i do not understand why, but anyway now i can get all those files back. xD